# can't create project in GitLab 5.0

Tags: git, gitlab

When I try to create project in GitLab 5.0 web interface, it show error -

```
Can't save project. Please try again later
```

I have no information about this error in logs, only -

```
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-29 12:36:06 +0400
Processing by ProjectsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"вњ“", "authenticity_token"=>"2fl+iBv2IggV6RVQP2M41lzeQRWT2hnow1qfG4NVxbQ=", "project"=>{"name"=>"sdfsdf", "namespace_id"=>"GLN", "import_url"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create project"}
  Rendered projects/_new_form.html.haml (8.5ms)
  Rendered projects/create.js.haml (9.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 119ms (Views: 10.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.8ms)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your environment, it can be:

- an issue during the installation, as illustrated with [issue 3743](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3743),
- or a missing package, as in [issue 3328](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3328).

The second point was resolved with:

```
echo "deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t squeeze-backports install redis-server
```

Comment: Thank you very much, second variant is correct

Comment: running "sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production" both redis and git were two low on the version for gitlab 5.3 I used backports to update git to 1.7.10 as well and it worked after that.